# I can't get a filter to work on a customized tumblr page

Tags: javascript, css, filtering

I'm fairly new to coding, and I thought I had a good enough grasp on it to add a filter to a premade page, but I'm having issues getting the filter to work on the code below. The two infoboxes are supposed to be visible when you click "all" or "verse a" but not when you click "verse b" or any of the other buttons. If anyone can help, I'd be really grateful! The page itself is [here](http://marvel-babies.tumblr.com/characters).

```
#filters {
top: 10;
left: 0;
height: 50px;
width: 100%;
position: fixed !important;
z-index: 999999;
text-align:center;
}

#filters a:visited {
color:#ffffff;
text-transform:uppercase;
font-style:italic;
background:#6fc8de;
padding:3px 10px 3px 10px;
margin-left:3px;
margin-right:3px;
text-decoration:none;
letter-spacing:1px;
}

#filters a:hover {
color:#6fc8de;
background:#202020;
}

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.filters').click(function() {
e.preventDefault();
$(".media").not("." + $(this).attr("rel")).hide(500);
$("." + $(this).attr("rel")).show(500);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please post the bit of JavaScript that you are having a problem with and not your entire file?

Comment: Please people, always properly indent the code that you are posting. Just put it in a snippet and use the tidy functionality.

Comment: @WebWanderer Seconded.

Comment: @WebWanderer Okay, I think I just have the JavaScript now... or at least the javascript and the css. Still getting the hang of this.

Comment: if you aren't going to pair down the script, can you add a comment near the lines that aren't working as you expect? Optionally, provide a sample on jsbin, plnkr.co, etc

Comment: @Aelliott1485 Okay, I think I narrowed it down to the filter script and css.

Comment: okay - I haven't used code similar to what you are using here but I made [an example in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5BNkfLMtNYTlRwzlUsl6?p=preview) - does that not work like you expect? if so, how should it function differently?

Comment: @Aelliott1485 No, if you go to the page and try to click on the links, the infoboxes stay where they are. Yours is how I want it to work, but it, for whatever reason, isn't translating to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there were two errors on your page originally (sorry we had you condense your code but it was too much to try and decipher, looking for flaws). If you look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XXPGufluxY7JvuMdDQhT?p=preview) you will see I have taken your original code (available from your [earlier revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39539101/revisions)) and modified two lines:

## 1. Include the infinite scroll plugin

```
//add this line to include the infinite scroll plugin
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-infinitescroll/2.0b2.120519/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/6hsqxdt/QBym35odk/jquery.masonry.js">
```

## 2.In the click function - accept event argument

We need to accept the event argument *e* as a parameter:

```
//accept argument e here, to avoid an error where 'e' is undefined in the call to preventDefault()
$('a.filters').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".media").not("." + $(this).attr("rel")).hide(500);
    $("." + $(this).attr("rel")).show(500);
});
```

### Edit:

We discovered that omitting the time parameter on the call to *.hide()* got the elements to hide as desired.

Comment: Okay, so I added that stuff, but when I click the "verse b" button, I can still see both boxes.

Comment: Hmm - I tried removing the parameter to `.hide()` and that appears to hide the elements... I would suggest that you read up on [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)..

Comment: I tried that on my own without success, but copying your plunker made it work. You are a magician, and I thank you very much. :)

Comment: Nice- if you like that answer, would you mind accepting it? Thanks!